# Como puedo resolver este problema con Javascript para recorrer arrays dentro de arrays?

Tags: javascript, array, funciones, bucles, objeto

El ejercicio es el siguiente: Tengo un objeto que representa un arbol de navidad, en el que tengo "values", que representa la cantidad de adornos que tiene esa parte del arbol. Despues se van haciendo "ramas" al arbol (left, right), siendo algunos de éstos otros objetos con la misma estructura.

EJEMPLO DE ARBOL:

```
        const bigTree = {
        value: 1,
        left: {
            value: 5,
            left: {
                value: 7,
                left: {
                    value: 3,
                    left: null,
                    right: null
                },
                right: null
            },
            right: null
        },
        right: {
            value: 6,
            left: {
                value: 5,
                left: null,
                right: null
            },
            right: {
                value: 1,
                left: null,
                right: null
            }
        }
    }
```

Yo lo que quiero hacer es crear una funcion que lo que haga sea recorrer cada capa del objeto, y que cuando encuentre una propiedad "value", tome el valor y lo guarde en una variable para ir contando los adornos. Y por otro lado que se verifique si una propiedad es un tipo de dato "object", y si es asi que se puede aplicar la misma funcion recursivamente (como un bucle).

Yo lo intenté hacer primero transformando el objeto en un array porque creí que sería mas facil recorrerlo, pero al momento de hacer la funcion recursiva no se como hacerlo. O si tambien debo usar algun bucle "for".

ACA LO QUE HICE HASTA AHORA:

```
    function countDecorations(tree) {

        let values = [];

        
        objectToArray = Object.entries(tree);
        console.log(objectToArray);
       

        function filtro(nivelParaFiltrar) {

            nivelParaFiltrar.filter(nivel => {                                 

                if(nivel[0] == 'value') {                                         
                    values.push(nivel[1]);                                       
                    console.log(nivel);
                };
                if(typeof nivel[1] === 'object') {                                
                    subnivel = nivel;
                    console.log(subnivel);
                    filtro(subnivel);
                }     
                
            })          
        };

        filtro(objectToArray);

        console.log(values);          
    }
```

Y que se llame a la funcion por medio de:

```
countDecorations(bigTree);
```

Mi idea es que se pueda recorrer todo el arbol automatizadamente sin saber como es su estructura interna. Y que a medida que se lo vaya recorriendo vaya guardando los "values" en una variable, y la funcion termine retornando la cantidad final de adornos, que vendria a ser la suma total de los valores de las propiedades "value".

Desde ya muchas gracias. Abrazo

Comment: Es idea mía o esto es exactamente un [recorrido de árboles binarios](https://www.delftstack.com/es/tutorial/data-structure/binary-tree-traversal/)? Creo que leer el artículo y practicar por tu cuenta te servirá muchisimo más como desarrollador, que esperar sentado la respuesta... Pero to each its own, supongo. Espero el enlace te sea de utilidad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para recorrer el arbol empleariamos una función recursiva, el cual recibiría la estructura de tipo arbol. Dentro de la función retornariamos el valor del campo value sumado al valor del subarbol izquierdo y derecho (si estos existiesen).
En el ámbito de los árboles binarios, a este recorrido se le denomina recorrido preorden. No te vendría mal leer un poco más sobre eso. [arboles binarios](https://medium.com/@matematicasdiscretaslibro/cap%C3%ADtulo-12-teoria-de-arboles-binarios-f731baf470c0)

```js
function countDecorations(bigTree) {
  return bigTree['value'] + (!!bigTree['left']? countDecorations(bigTree['left']) : 0) + (!!bigTree['right']? countDecorations(bigTree['right']) : 0)
}

console.log("Cantidad final de adornos: ",countDecorations({
  value: 1,
  left: {
    value: 2, 
    left: null,
    right: null
  },
  right: {
    value: 3,
    left: null,
    right: null
  }
}))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias José. Voy a leer mas sobre los arboles binarios. Nunca habia escuchado de eso, me lo sugirieron tambien en el anterior comentario. Este ejercicio surgio de practicas que estoy haciendo por mi cuenta. De repente vi este ejercicio que encontre por internet, y me surgió esa duda de que pasa si no conociera la estructura interna para recorrerlo y tomar los valores. Mil gracias, voy a seguir practicando y por supuesto estudiando bien los arboles binarios jeje. Abrazo.